# How to read a char* string by fread function?

Tags: c, memory, char, fread

We called a library to read text, this library API only accepts a `FILE*` pointer. It actually reads file text by `fread()` call internally.

But we also need to use this library to read text from a `char*` string rather than a `FILE*`.

Of course we can write the `char*` string into a temp file but we're not allowed to do this for some reasons...

How to do ? Thanks !!

Comment: Who says you're not allowed, by the way? You may need to _educate_ them (as in "educate with a big stick").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [fmemopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html)

The fmemopen() function shall associate the buffer given by the buf argument with a stream.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char buffer[] = "foobar";

int main (void)
{
  FILE *stream;

  stream = fmemopen (buffer, strlen (buffer), "r");

  /* You got a FILE* pointer, you can call your function here :-) */
}
```

Comment: That is not C, it's POSIX. You should specify its non-portability.

Comment: +1, but as @paxdiablo pointed out it's a (recent) POSIX addition. Epic tip though, thanks for mentioning this. *Goes to look for a recent enough POSIX system to play on*.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, but it's not easy and quite complicated.

You can create a shared-memory file handle with [`shm_open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/shm_open.html), this file handle can the be used by [`mmap`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) to make it point to the memory area of the string, then use [`fdopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fdopen.html) to create a `FILE` pointer from the file descriptor.

**Note:** This will only work on POSIX (e.g. Linux or Mac OSX) systems. Windows systems should have similar functionality, but it still won't be easy.

**Edit** It's probably something similar to this that happens behind the scenes in the `fmemopen` call referenced in the answer by Massimo Fazzolari.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, short of writing your own device driver to communicate back with the process somehow, this is a tricky one. By that, I mean you could create a character device which would, when read from, communicate via some sort of IPC (shared memory, named pipes, or other things) back to the process.

But this is (1) nasty, (2) UNIX-specific (non-portable) and (3) a very bad idea :-)

Without such low-level tricks (or with non-portable extensions that can treat memory like file handles), this cannot be done - `fread` expects a `FILE*` and will read from a file handle, that's it, really.

Comment: Not sure why you downvoted. This is indeed _impossible_ based on the tags you provided. It cannot be done in standard C and, even though it's _possible_ under UNIX/Linux-type systems with my method, it's still a bad idea.

Comment: @nos, when the question specifies only C (without a qualifier like Linux), I take that as meaning ISO C.

Answer (score 0):

On various unix systems, you can create a pipe/socket or similar file descriptors, and use fdopen() to open the file descriptor and get a FILE* pointer. Then feed the string into the pipe/socket.

I suggest you check you program/library design when you run into strange problems like this. Strange problems/requirements are strong indications of bad designs.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think this can be done. fread can read only from a file stream i.e either FILE * or stdout.

Comment: Manik, I think you meant `stdin` but, in any case, that's still a `FILE*`, so superfluous :-)